# Adding logging interceptor to wso2 microgateway

Tags: wso2, wso2-micro-gateway

I am using wso2 microgateway to proxy our backend api. I need to write a logging interceptor which can log the access events and auth/security related logging events to a separate log file.

From the sample java interceptor, I could understand that the wso2 mgw uses slf4j api and binds to java util logging api. The logs are written to microgateway.log file in the gateway runtime tool.

What is the best way to accomplish this requirement?

Comment: Since microgateway uses ballerina provided java util logging, and the log properties file is not exposed, you can plugin logging framework like log4j for your interceptors. Please refer pull request[1], which we have also included log4j for the native java codes in microgateway
[1] - https://github.com/wso2/product-microgateway/pull/1245/files

Comment: Using other logging framework like log4j will not work consistently. Since wso2 uses slf4j api, the binding of slf4j with log4j depends on which impl gets picked up from the classpath. In our testing, sometimes log4j got picked up and sometimes JDK14 logging got picked up.